# Displaying Associative array values using HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, object, associative-array

I want to display the value of an associative array using html elements, but I can't seem to get the values because it always outputs undefine.

my code works like this : the user will register data, the registered data will be stored in an object and will be using a key "username" to access it. When a user search a username the values must be displayed using html elements.

here is my code. thank you

```
var storage = [];

function viewUserArray()
{   
    var zName = document.getElementById('checkArray').value;
    var html = "<h1> Username Details </h1>";
    var anotherhtml = "<p>";
    var uName;
    var fName;
    var elmail;
    var pword;
    var b_day;
    var g_nder;

    for (key in storage)
    {
        if(key === zName)
        {
            uName = storage[key].uName;
            fName = storage[key].fName;
            elmail = storage[key].elmail;
            pword = storage[key].pword;
            b_day = storage[key].b_day;
            g_nder = storage[key].g_nder;

            html +=  "<p>Username : " + uName + "</p>";
            html +=  "<p>Full Name : " + fName + "</p>";
            html +=  "<p>Email : " + elmail + "</p>";
            html +=  "<p>Password : " + pword + "</p>";
            html +=  "<p>Age : " + b_day + "</p>";
            html +=  "<p>Gender : " + g_nder + "</p>";
        }
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = html;
    }
}

function setValuesArray()
{
    var uName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var fName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    var elmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var b_day = getAge();
    var g_nder = document.getElementById('gender').value;

    storage[uName] = (storage[uName]||[]).concat({//add user to storage[uName]
      "Username" : uName,
      "Full Name" : fName,
      "Email" : elmail,
      "Password" : pword,
      "Age" :  b_day,
      "Gender" : g_nder                   
    });
}
```

Comment: I already told you in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167028/display-an-associative-array-in-a-multidimensional-array-javascript): JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, It has arrays and object literals. You defined storage as array but use string keys to set values.

Comment: What's the usecase of `setValuesArray` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much same as other answer:

```
var storage = {};

function viewUserArray()
{   
    var zName = document.getElementById('checkArray').value;
    var html = "<h1> Username Details </h1>";
    var anotherhtml = "<p>";
    var uName;
    var fName;
    var elmail;
    var pword;
    var b_day;
    var g_nder;
    if(!storage[zName]){
      console.log("doesn't exist");
      return;
    }

    uName = storage[zName].uName;
    fName = storage[zName].fName;
    elmail = storage[zName].elmail;
    pword = storage[zName].pword;
    b_day = storage[zName].b_day;
    g_nder = storage[zName].g_nder;

    html +=  "<p>Username : " + uName + "</p>";
    html +=  "<p>Full Name : " + fName + "</p>";
    html +=  "<p>Email : " + elmail + "</p>";
    html +=  "<p>Password : " + pword + "</p>";
    html +=  "<p>Age : " + b_day + "</p>";
    html +=  "<p>Gender : " + g_nder + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = html;
    }
}

function setValuesArray()
{
    var uName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var fName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    var elmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var b_day = getAge();
    var g_nder = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    //I assume there is only one uName so update the uName if it exist and create it if it doesn't
    // storage[uName] = (storage[uName]||[]).concat({//add user to storage[uName]
    storage[uName] = {//update or add
      uName,
      fName,
      elmail,
      pword,
      b_day,
      g_nder                   
    };
}
```

You also don't consistently get the values under the same keys that you save them in:

You save a user as: `"Username" : uName,` but then magically expect to get the value with: `storage[zName].uName` Saving a value under key "Username" but then try to get the value using a key "uName"